# Trying to move by point.x / .y less than 1

Tags: actionscript-3, floating-point, flash-cs4

I'm trying to return a point from a method that calculates angle as a vector.

I'm then adding this points x & y to my player object (from example code)'s x and y Numbers - these are Numbers, not a point. In other places I see numbers defined as floats, so I didn't expect this to be a problem.

When I multiply distvar and distvar2 by * 2, then my object move, best I can tell because the values, formerly .59~ & -.8~, are greater than 1 (absolute value).

Any hints? Should I just use a Point variable on my player object instead? Is there something else I must do to convert from a point.x/y to a Number? New to flash, appreciate your help.

Thanks!

```
public function GetAngle(initialp:Point,secondp:Point):Point{
    distvar = ((initialp.x - secondp.x) * (initialp.x - secondp.x));
    distvar2 = ((initialp.y - secondp.y) * (initialp.y - secondp.y));

 //Emergency guard clause against dividing by 0
    if (distvar + distvar2 == 0){
        distvar = 1;
        distvar2 = 1;
    }
    veldistance = Math.sqrt((distvar+distvar2));

distvar = ((Math.abs(initialp.x-secondp.x))/veldistance);
distvar2 = ((Math.abs(initialp.y-secondp.y))/veldistance);

if (secondp.x < initialp.x){
    distvar = -distvar;
}
if (secondp.y < initialp.y){
    distvar2 = -distvar2;
}

apoint.x = distvar;
apoint.y = distvar2;

return apoint;
```

Comment: `var veldistance:Number = Math.sqrt(distvar+distvar2);` and `return new Point(distvar, distvar2);` might help

Comment: Thanks, I was formerly setting veldistance as an instance variable instead of local to that method. Was wondering how to do that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of a point.x/y are numbers.  The way you are adding the point.x/y to your object.x/y should be fine.  I suspect there is something else wrong with the code, though without more of your code I'm not sure what. For one, I can't see where **apoint** is created.

Comment: I do initialize apoint when the class loads:   private var apoint:Point = new Point();